# The (See more) text doesn't convert to (See less) text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I added a "See more" text at the end of a paragraph because it is too long. I want that when I click on the "See more" text, the entire paragraph, along with the text "See more," should be replaced with "See less," and the "See less" text should appear at the end of the paragraph. However, the "See more" text is not changing to "See less," and it remains in the same position.

[Image to explain where the text is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19F3j.png)

[Image to explain where the text should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s81oP.png)

## **CSS**

```
 /*Lower Side*/
            .lowerside{
                margin-top: 38.3%;
                width: 100%;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                background-color: #F0F2F5;
                min-height: 200vh;
                position: relative;
            }

            /*Left Side*/
            .lowerside-left{
                width: 360px;
                top: 5%;
                margin-left: 17%;
                margin-bottom: 0.5%;
                margin-top: -6%;
                border-radius: 8px;
                display: block;
                background-color: white;
                overflow-x: hidden;
                overflow-y: hidden;
                box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
                position: absolute;
            }

            /*Left Side Text*/
            .lowerside-left-text{
                font-family: "Segoe UI", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                padding: 10px 16px 4px;
                position: relative;
            }

            /*Left Side Icon*/
            .lowerside-left-icon{
                padding: 5px 16px 4px;
                position: relative;
                border: none;
                border-radius: 0;
            }

            /*Hide Extra long text*/
            .text-preview{
                display: -webkit-box;
                -webkit-line-clamp: 4;
                overflow: hidden;
                -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
            }

            /*Height after full text*/
            .lowerside-left-fulltext{
                height: 410px;
            }

            /*See More*/
            .seemore{
                font-family: "Segoe UI", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                font-size: 15px;
                font-weight: 600;
                overflow: visible;
                position: absolute;
            }

            .seemore:hover{
                cursor: pointer;
                text-decoration: underline;
            }

            /*See Less*/
            .seeless{
                font-family: "Segoe UI", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                font-size: 15px;
                font-weight: 600;
                position: absolute;        
            }

            .seeless:hover{
                cursor: pointer;
                text-decoration: underline;
            }

            /*Right Side*/
            .lowerside-right{
                width: 480px;
                top: 5%;
                margin-left: 47%;
                margin-bottom: 0.5%;
                margin-top: -6%;
                border-radius: 8px;
                display: block;
                background-color: white;
                overflow-x: hidden;
                overflow-y: hidden;
                box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
                position: absolute;
            }
```

## **HTML**

```
<!--Lower Side-->
        <div class="lowerside">

            <!--Left Side-->
            <div class="lowerside-left" id="about-section">
                <!--Left Side Text-->
                <h3 class="lowerside-left-text" style="font-weight: bolder;">About</h3>
                <p class="lowerside-left-text" style="color:#216fdb; font-size: small; font-weight:light; padding-left: 85%; margin-top: -14%;cursor: pointer;">See all</p>
                <!--Left Side Icon and Text-->
                <img class="lowerside-left-icon" src="I icon.png">
                <p class="lowerside-left-text" style="font-size: 15px; padding-left: 13%; margin-top: -11%;">The Facebook app Page celebrates how our friends inspire us, support us, and help us discover the world when we connect.</p>
                <!--Left Side Icon and Text-->
                <img class="lowerside-left-icon" src="I icon.png">
                <p class="lowerside-left-text text-preview" style="font-size: 15px; padding-left: 13%; margin-top: -11%;">Community Values<br>
                    We believe people can do more together than alone and that each of us plays an important role in helping to create a safe and respectful community. So, we’ve laid out a set of principles for us to follow on this Page:<br><br>
                    Let’s celebrate the things that bring us together.<br><br>
                    Let’s choose to treat each other like neighbors rather than strangers.<br><br>
                    Let’s respect individuality and welcome diverse backgrounds and perspectives.<br><br>
                    Let’s assume people mean well.<br><br>
                    Our moderators are here for the community to uphold these values every day.</p>
                    <!--See More-->
                    <span class="seemore" onclick="toggleOverflow()" style="left: 13%; bottom: 43%;">See more</span>
                    <script>
                    function toggleOverflow() {
                        var paragraph = document.querySelector('.lowerside-left-text.text-preview');
                        var seeMore = document.querySelector('.seemore');
                        var seeLess = document.querySelector('.seeless');

                        if (paragraph.classList.contains('lowerside-left-fulltext')) {
                            // If the text is in full view, clicking "See more" should show truncated text
                            paragraph.classList.remove('lowerside-left-fulltext');
                            seeMore.textContent = 'See more';
                        } else {
                            // If the text is truncated, clicking "See more" should show the full text
                            paragraph.classList.add('lowerside-left-fulltext');
                            seeMore.textContent = 'See less';
                        }
                    }
                    </script>
                    <span class="seeless" onclick="toggleOverflow()" style="display: none; left: 13%; bottom: 43%;">See less</span><!--See Less-->
                <!--Left Side Icon and Text-->
                <img class="lowerside-left-icon" src="black_like.png" style="bottom: -13px;">
                <p class="lowerside-left-text" style="font-size: 15px; padding-left: 13%; margin-top: -7%;">183,205,742 people like this</p>
                <!--Left Side Icon and Text-->
                <img class="lowerside-left-icon" src="follow.png" style="margin-top: -6px;">
                <p class="lowerside-left-text" style="font-size: 15px; padding-left: 13%; margin-top: -11%;">188,661,607 people follow this</p>
                <!--Left Side Icon and Text-->
                <img class="lowerside-left-icon" src="check.png" style="margin-top: -6px;">
                <p class="lowerside-left-text" style="font-size: 15px; padding-left: 13%; margin-top: -11%;">118 people checked in here</p>
                <!--Left Side Icon and Text-->
                <img class="lowerside-left-icon" src="World.png" style="margin-top: -6px;">
                <p class="lowerside-left-text" style="font-size: 15px; padding-left: 13%; margin-top: -11%;"><a href="Link" style="color: #216fdb; text-decoration: none;">Link</a></p>
                <!--Left Side Icon and Text-->
                <img class="lowerside-left-icon" style="margin-top: -6px; margin-left: 15px; background-image: url(file.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 0px -300px; filter: contrast(0); height: 20px; width: 20px;">
                <p class="lowerside-left-text" style="font-size: 15px; padding-left: 13%; margin-top: -9%;"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/category/internet-company" style="color: #216fdb; text-decoration: none;">Internet Company</a></p>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're not using the `seeless` element at all, but just attempting to change the text of the `seemore` element.

Instead of changing the text, try changing the display of the respective elements instead, since you have them already:

```
if (paragraph.classList.contains('lowerside-left-fulltext')) {
   // If the text is in full view, clicking "See more" should show truncated text
   paragraph.classList.remove('lowerside-left-fulltext');
   seeMore.style.display = 'block';
   seeLess.style.display = 'none';
} else {
   // If the text is truncated, clicking "See more" should show the full text
   paragraph.classList.add('lowerside-left-fulltext');
   seeMore.style.display = 'none';
   seeLess.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: Hello!, thanks for helping me, I tried using your code but unfortunately, the problem wasn't solved. Do you have another solution? I will be happy to hear. Thanks again for finding a solution!

Comment: It works in this codepen: https://codepen.io/Hobscotch/pen/LYMXzJd
(The styling is a bit off, but the functionality works.)
Can you describe what was happening when you tried the above solution?

Comment: Yes, but there is nothing to describe because nothing changes in the output the problems remain as it is and I visited the link you gave the "see more" text changed to "see less" but it didn't change its position, for your help, you can see the images I gave above in my question.

Comment: Oops, I had pasted your code in the JS window of the codepen. />_<\
It's updated it now.
(I also took away the "bottom: 43%" from the "seeless" element.)
Also consider moving your script section to either the top or the bottom of the html, rather than having it sit in the middle.

Comment: Yes! It's really working the same as I want in Codepen, but unfortunately, it's not working in VS Code. Do you have any solution? I will be very happy to know!

Comment: If the only difference between the codepen and your local is the position of the JS, it might be worth moving it out from between the spans. I would recommend putting it right at the bottom, before the body closing tag - that way, all the html is there before it tries to run anything. I don't know if it will fix it, though, since your function only runs on click.
Did you remove the "bottom: 43%" from `<span class="seeless" onclick="toggleOverflow()" style="display: none; left: 13%">See less</span>`?

Comment: yes, I have removed the "bottom:43%" from the given code and I also tried putting the JS code at the bottom before the body closing tag but nothing works :(

Comment: Eish, then I honestly have no idea. There might be something else messing with it that we're not thinking of.

Comment: Hey! I didn't include the full code for my project because it's too long. The code I provided only works because it's the only related JS code. However, my project has three JS files before the closing body tags, and one of them contains the code I provided here. When I remove the other two files, the code works correctly. But I can't remove them because they're important. Do you have any idea? Please help me this time I promise I will not ask any questions again and will not disturb you again. How can I give you those javascript code files?

Comment: And I got another surprise! I found a JS file that whenever I remove it from the project it works correctly but when I add it again it doesn't. Here is the [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Shumaila2/Facebook-Clone-Page/main/adjust-section.js) of the code file which makes other code not work correctly! I didn't see any fault in this code but see if you find it.